# Connect to ODBC and export data as CSV?

Tags: snow-leopard, csv

Is there a way I can connect to a data source via ODBC and export the data to a CSV file on the mac? Open-source software to do this would be great, otherwise is it possible from the command-line?

Comment: Possibly  http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_premium/premium_detail_mac.html

Comment: Is writing a simple Java app an option?  Should be easy to do.  Admittedly it would JDBC instead of ODBC.

Comment: @Mark - From my (windows) experience with Navicat Premium, it can only export data from MySQL, SQL server, PostgreSQL. You can import data from ODBC to one of said DBs and then export it to CSV as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Most scripting languages should be able to do this e.g. python, perl, tcl,

Python does this with

1. AN odbc pachkage - see [Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ODBC)
2. [csv package](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) in the
   standard library

Answer (score 1):

[Razor SQL](http://www.razorsql.com/download_mac.html) has a fully functional 30-day trial which would be ok for one-time uses.

Answer (score 0):

I spent several days trying to get this to work for a client. There are lots of ODBC drivers and SQL software packages that promise to do it, but in the end I had to run a virtual machine of Windows and Office 2010 to get this to work.

Not really sure why, but just wanted to let you know what I had to do to get it to work.